ODEs solved by physics-informed neural networks
Is it possible that an ODE (with an IC) solution by physics informed neural networks (PINNs) turns out to be a mixture of several branch solutions of the same bulk ODE but with different ICs, even when the loss function is very low? E.g. u'(t)=1 is solved by PINNs as the union of u=t for some t interval and u=t+1 for the remaining t interval.

I would say it depends on the ODE, the distance between initial conditions and the final value of the loss function. In the literature, I see that the value of the loss function during training is about 1e-6, and it is about 1e-4 during testing. There are infinitely many functions with such loss function values, and they may be quite far apart from each other in classical sense. PINNs are notoriously bad at predicting chaotic systems, for example. This generally attributed to accuracy, but I don't know any further than that.

Does anyone have any idea what PINNs actually do? Is what you describe possible? It would say anything is possible with PINNs.

@WolfgangBangerth no one has a serious answer for that, yet. It is sad to see computational math is getting rid of math.

@WolfgangBangerth, maybe a handful of people put effort to make it rigorous. The results are lacking. Basically, the neural network is a proposed solution to the ODE/PDE, if the neural network "space" contains the solution then the optimization process will find it. If the "space" is rich enough (basically universal approximation theorem) then the solution can be general enough to depend on the parameters of the problem. I think there are some researchers who derived worst case bounds, and the neural network has to be massive to have any sort of error bound guarantees.

@Yimin There is some effort, but I don't know how serious it is: https://sites.google.com/view/physmlworkshop24/home . It looks like to me (as an outsider) there is interest, but it also seems like the interest comes from an application perspective, e.g. not too much interest in relating the solution quality to the effort in computation.

@AbdullahAliSivas I am also an outsider. I agree that the PINN community is application-driven and might be pleased with two-digit accuracy. I am just wondering if someone can provide a deeper understanding, e.g., before solving a problem with PINN, can we at least show a guaranteed error analysis like other traditional methods?

@Yimin https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.01806 is probably the only paper I know about what you're asking.

@NNN just went through the paper, it made an unreasonable assumption about having the global minimizer found for any sample size. This might be possible if the landscape is trivial, e.g. quadratic-like, under NTK regime, this is true, but that is an uninteresting case. Otherwise, the landscape is guaranteed to be non-convex. I would say the paper made some effort but not what I ask for.

There are also some works on error estimation for PINNs by Siddharthra Mishra, e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.16144.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.09346.pdf

@JulianRoth Neither of them studied the training behavior, they are more or less about the generalization error. If the network is trained to certain state which gives small loss, then the solution's error can be quantified. That does not answer the question, how do we know PINN can achieve a small loss before we run the code.

@Yimin, Results similar to what you want are "Space-time error estimates for deep neural network approximations for differential equations" by Grohs et al. and contents of the course Numerical Analysis of Neural Networks by Roland Maier https://www.math.kit.edu/ianm_jrg_numpde/edu/nann2024s/en . You can follow references and citations from there if you want, however as I mentioned before, the effort is galiant but the results are lacking.

If you abstract the learning problem to instead learning the action of operators on the state space (operator inference) instead of directly learning the solution of a given PDE, you can take advantage of much more theory to derive or robustly estimate some nice error bounds in some cases, see here for example https://www.annualreviews.org/content/journals/10.1146/annurev-fluid-121021-025220

Yes, I believe it is possible.
For the ODE you showed, one would minimize a loss of the following form
$$
\mathcal{L} = w_{init}\mathcal{L}_{init}  + w_{pde}\mathcal{L}_{pde}
$$
where $\mathcal{L}_{init}$ is the initial condition loss, and $\mathcal{L}_{pde}$ is the pde loss. As long as these losses are balanced, one would expect the solution obtained from the PINN to be close to the true solution of the ODE.
However, if $w_{pde}\mathcal{L}_{pde} \gg w_{init}\mathcal{L}_{init}$ because the weights are imbalanced, or if the pde loss is very high, then the optimizer may effectively ignore the initial condition and preferentially minimize $\mathcal{L}_{pde}$ and you might get the non-uniqueness you are asking about.

Thanks for your answer. But what my question assumes is that the loss function is sufficiently low so that both in your terminology Ls are small, then ICs are assumed satisfied.

Sorry I misunderstood. In "Physics-informed neural networks: A deep learning framework for solving forward and inverse problems involving nonlinear partial differential equations" by Raissi et. al. JCP, the authors present several examples in which the PINN solution is effectively discontinuous in space Fig 2, Fig A.6. Perhaps due to some pathological reason, your PINN predicts solutions which are discontinuous in time. For t < T_crit  it's solutions satisfy the IC and for t > T_crit  it's solutions do not satisfy the IC.  The loss will be low, but IC information does not get to T > T_crit.

Thanks for pointing that JCP paper out. That the loss will be low but IC information does not get to T > T_crit,  I wonder if this is your viewpoint or is that from the JCP paper?

This is my viewpoint, not the JCP paper's viewpoint. From my experience with physics based losses, they seem to be highly finicky and sensitive to parameters in the pde and possibly neural network and training hyperparameters, and getting stuck in a local minimum might be one of the symptoms of bad pde parameters/hyperparameters. Data based networks seem easier to train. See also section 5.1 in "An Expert’s Guide To Training Physics-Informed Neural Networks" by Wang, Perdikaris et. al.  Also see "Characterizing possible failure modes in physics-informed neural networks" by Krishnapriyan et.al.

I think you made a good point "For t < T_crit it's solutions satisfy the IC and for t > T_crit it's solutions do not satisfy the IC. The loss will be low, but IC information does not get to T > T_crit" in the second comment under this answer. I wonder if there is any existing work similar to that or in support of that.

I'm not aware existing work in support of my comment. But the section 5.1 I referred to in my previous comment is titled "Respecting Temporal Causality" and it may be relevant (I have't read it, it's on my reading list)

@feynman in "Respecting Causality Is All You Need For Training Physics-Informed Neural Networks" by Wang, Sankaran, Perdikaris, there is this comment "In fact, as we will see in section 3, continuous-time PINNs trained by gradient descent are implicitly biased towards first approximating PDE solutions at later times,before even resolving the initial conditions, therefore profoundly violating temporal causality."  This may have something to do with your observation.

Absolutely. If only this could be more explainable.
